# Snowflake stage gives: SQL compilation error: Option SNAPPY_COMPRESSION is not valid for file format type PARQUET

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, compression, stage, snappy

Snowflake stage gives: SQL compilation error: Option SNAPPY_COMPRESSION is not valid for file format type PARQUET.

Please give UPDATE STAGE statement?

Comment: Please update your question with the CREATE STAGE statement and, if you are using a pre-defined file format, the CREATE FILE FORMAT statement

Answer (score 0):

Example STAGE query which works for create or update SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE Test1StagedMyNumber
URL = 's3://com-bosco-test/table-data/my_number/data.parquet'
CREDENTIALS = ( AWS_KEY_ID = 'AAA' AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'BBB' )
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'PARQUET' COMPRESSION = 'SNAPPY' )
```